# Dynamically changing select based on other param select in same form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have form that has a country and state params.  Depending on the country chosen, I want the state to change to lessen the choices.

I have helpers for the states and countries

**I tried:**

```
<%= f.select(:country, options_for_select((countries), @stripe_account[:country]), {}, { class: "form-control input-lg" }) %>


  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :address_state, "State/Province/Region" %>
     <div class="field <%= @stripe_account.country == 'US' ? 'present' : 'hidden' %>">
       <%= f.select(:address_state, options_for_select((us_states), @stripe_account[:address_state]), {}, { class: "form-control input-lg", id: "address_state us-states"}) %>
     </div>
     <div class= "field <%= @stripe_account.country == 'AU' ? 'present' : 'hidden' %>">
       <%= f.select(:address_state, options_for_select((au_regions), @stripe_account[:address_state]), {}, { class: "form-control input-lg", id: "address_state au_regions"}) %>
     </div>
...
</div>
```

This doesn't seem to work.  And another thing I do not like about it, is it only hides the form but doesn't hide the style.  So its just hidden and there is a blank area of space.

**I have done stuff like this for other forms but seems to not work unless it's in HTML:**

```
  $("#country").on("change",function(){"US"===$(this).val()?$("#banking-us, #banking-us-1").show():$("#banking-us, #banking-us-1").hide()});
```

I tried this with the rails form, but didn't seem to work.

All of the choices are based on helpers for the form such as:

```
def countries
  [
    ['US'],
    ['AU'],
  ]
end
```

How can I do this?

Comment: rails forms don't have that functionality, you need to use JS like you showed.

Comment: The JS i show only works on html forms from what ive tested.  Any ideas for using it on rails forms?

Comment: The rails form is an HTML form, it's just built using Ruby. It's still run as HTML / CSS / JS on the browser.

Comment: Just ended up doing the JS code i posted above with html country inputs that fire off on divs for the longer lists of states.  works out so far.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the Carmen plugin:

http://autonomousmachine.com/posts/2009/4/1/carmen-a-rails-plugin-for-geographic-names-and-abbreviations

You can also check this other stackoverflow post:

Ruby on Rails Country/State Select Enigma